# Find empty slot in a List of Object for a schedule in Java

Tags: java, android, json, list

I am writing an app in Java in which I want to show a full schedule of the shop and when the person comes in/out and when there is no person. please check the attached picture.enter image description here

The list of persons are in a JSON file :

```
{
  "venue": {
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "Foursquare HQ",
    "openTime": 1479798000000,
    "closeTime": 1479864600000,
    "visitors": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Dave",
        "arriveTime": 1479805200000,
        "leaveTime": 1479816000000
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Elizabeth",
        "arriveTime": 1479801600000,
        "leaveTime": 1479819600000
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Ben",
        "arriveTime": 1479826800000,
        "leaveTime": 1479830400000
      },...
```

this json is extracted and can be access by a method called getVisitors and it returned a List. The class Person is declared as below:

```
public final class Person{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private long arriveTime;
    private long leaveTime;

    public Person(int id, String name, long arriveTime, long leaveTime){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.arriveTime = arriveTime;
        this.leaveTime = leaveTime;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public long getArriveTime() {
        return arriveTime;
    }

    public long getLeaveTime() {
        return leaveTime;
    }
}
```

My problem is how to add the "No visitors" items? the first one and last one can be added using

```
list.add(idx, element)
```

but I do not see an easy algorithm to find the empty spot during the day between visitors.

The "No Visitors" must appear when in the shop no visitors shows up. basically any gap between 2 visitors and based on the overall openTime and closeTime of the store

I am using a RecycledView to display the information as a list as shown below :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView rvRecyclerView;
    private static PersonAdapter personAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rvRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvRecyclerView);
        rvRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        if(personAdapter == null)
            personAdapter = new PersonAdapter();

        //set the adapter of the recycler view to push data.
        rvRecyclerView.setAdapter(personAdapter);

        Log.d(TAG, "ON CREATE CALL");
        new VenueFetcher(this).execute();
    }
```

VenueFetch is an AsyncTask who is in charge of extracting the JSON from the JSON file and use the call to

```
    mainActivity.personAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to update the list that part work

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add "No visitors" item to your list. Just sort the Person list based on their arriveTime, then iterate over the list and check if leaveTime of the current Person is lesser than the arriveTime of the next Person in the list.

Comment: Ok but I need to display it in the list show in the recycle view. How can I display them is I do not insert them in the list used by the adapter

Comment: Then you can add an element for each "currentPerson[leaveTime] < nextPerson[arriveTime]" in your list and sort them finally.